# Ignore empty dataframe when merging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have four df (df1,df2,df3,df4)

Sometimes df1 is null, sometimes df2 is null, sometimes df3 and df4 accordingly.

How can I do an outer merge so that the df which is empty is automatically ignored? I am using the below code to merge as of now:-

```
df = f1.result().merge(f2.result(), how='left', left_on='time', right_on='time').merge(f3.result(), how='left', left_on='time', right_on='time').merge(f4.result(), how='left', left_on='time', right_on='time')
```

and

```
df = reduce(lambda x,y: pd.merge(x,y, on='time', how='outer'), [f1.result(),f2.result(),f3.result(),f4.result()])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.empty`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) attribute or `len(df) > 0` to check whether the dataframe is empty or not.

**Try this:**

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
non_empty_dfs = [df for df in dfs if not df.empty]

df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right, on='time', how='outer'), non_empty_dfs)
```

Or, you could also filter empty dataframe as,

```
non_empty_dfs = [df for df in dfs if len(df) > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

use pandas' dataframe [empty](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) method, to filter out the empty dataframe, then you can concatenate or run whatever merge operation you have in mind:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[]}) #empty dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'B':[2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C':[3]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'D':[4]})

dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4]

#concat
#u can do other operations since u have gotten rid of the empty dataframe

pd.concat([df for df in dfs if not df.empty],axis=1)

    B   C   D
0   2   3   4
```

Comment: This works but supposes if one of the df has some missing DateTime index rows then it shifts the values. and do not return null for nonmatching values.  Suppose none of them are empty df but if df2 has four missing values then it shifts the values and always returns the last four rows as null.

Comment: yes, but that's why I specified merging. Thanks a lot for your answer!